# Questions about divorce

Tags: talaq

I had an argument with wife and she left the house. I spoke to her after few days and asked her to come back within 5 days els she should stay there. She said she will come back in few more days because shes angry. Would that constitute a divorce?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 1):

Divorce needs you to utter the words "you are divorced"!

If your wife left the house that might be a sinful act from her side. But how can divorce take place without you actively wanting or insisting on it?

Comment: It’s sinful for a wife to leave the house because she is upset with her husband? Are you sure?

Comment: @Loading... yep as nevertheless he is her guardian and she needs his permission to do so. Even in case of talaq she "must" remain in her hubsands house until the end of the 'iddah.

Comment: The wife needs the husbands permission to leave the house?

Comment: @Loading... strictly speaking yes, even if she wants to visit her parents. However in most cases this is not a big matter.

Comment: So if she goes to her parents or visits her friends without the husband knowing it’s a sin but the same vice versa isn’t?

Comment: @Loading... No it is a sin if she does so despite knowing that her husband doesn't want her to go there. Or if he "ordered" her not to do so (at a special time/case) .  As said in general the husband's agreement for that shouldn't be a big matter unless the husband misuses his rights as a guardian.

Comment: Alright thanks for the clarification.